# parse_dates is not working when read the csv using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

The following code is working fine if I give the dates with less than 2150 year.

Date format = YYYY-MM-DD
Input Data:
"2021-07-26","2500-04-30","2019-04-30"

```
df = pd.read_csv('files/Test_Excep.csv',
                 delimiter=",", 
                 parse_dates= ['col1_date','col2_date','col3_dt'],
                 infer_datetime_format=True)

df.dtypes
col1_date                          datetime64[ns]
col2_date                                 object
col3_dt                            datetime64[ns]
```

col2_date is showing as object and not datetime. It is showing as date if I use the date which is less than 2150 year means any date less than 2150 year.

Please let me know if any workaround for this.

Comment: funny thing: if i use a simple `datetime` parser, pandas append time only on `col2_date`, so the data is double-checked and `dateutil` is not to blame

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying.  Please let me know what is the solution to treat the col2_date as datetime

Comment: from datetime import datetime
custom_date_parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%d-%m")    date_parser=custom_date_parser - I still see the col2_date as object if i use this param in read_csv

Comment: [Timestamp limitations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations) "Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the time span that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years: 1677-09-21 00:12:43.145224193 - 2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807" There is some guidance in [Representing out-of-bounds spans](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans)

Comment: @mssr: yes that's why my comment starts with "funny thing" and not "this is your solution". `dateutil` is the library used for detecting date formats and if we shunt it with a custom date parser the problem still exists: the data is somehow parsed again. and as henri-ecker found out it was more of a storage problem than a parsing one but the information we got with this test still stands true (and funny)